# ACCEPTS vs smartmatch in Hashes: what's the difference?

Tags: raku

Theoretically,  ~~ is syntactic sugar for [`ACCEPTS`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map#method_ACCEPTS) so the last two lines should return the same value:

```
my %myth-objects =  %(Þor => "Mjólnir", Oðinn => "Hugin") ;
say %myth-objects;
say %myth-objects.ACCEPTS("Oðinn");
say %myth-objects ~~ "Oðinn";
```

However, the first returns `True` and the second returns `False`. What am I missing here?

Comment: What @ValleLukas says. `a ~~ b` reads as "`a` is accepted by `b`" or "`b` accepts `a`". (This is generically the case. It's not relevant what `a` or `b` are, hash or otherwise.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with what you have.

1. Smartmatch has two execution layers.

   one is immediate

   ```perl6
   'abc' ~~ $_ eq 'XYZ'
   ```

   `.ACCEPTS` is then called on the result, with the given value as the argument

   ```perl6
   do given 'abc' { ($_ eq 'XYZ').ACCEPTS($_) }
   #                 ^                    ^
   #                 |                    |
   #                 +------- 'abc'-------+
   ```

   In the above case `$_ eq 'XYZ'` is `False`, and `False.ACCEPTS(|)` always returns `False`.
   (Similarly `True.ACCEPTS(|)` always returns `True`.)

   You could also return a Callable.

   ```perl6
   'abc' ~~ * eq 'XYZ'
   ```

   This will appear to have the effect of removing the first immediate layer.
   (It doesn't actually do that though.)

   ```perl6
   do given 'abc' { (* eq 'XYZ').ACCEPTS($_) }
   do given 'abc' { (* eq 'XYZ').($_) }
   do given 'abc' { $_ eq 'XYZ' }
   ```

   Or it could return a type or literal.

   ```perl6
   'abc' ~~ ( 1 ?? Str !! Int ) # 'abc' ~~ Str
   do given 'abc' { ( 1 ?? Str !! Int ).ACCEPTS($_) }
   do given 'abc' { (      Str        ).ACCEPTS($_) }
                           Str         .ACCEPTS('abc')
   ```
2. You have the left hand side, and the right hand side swapped.

   These two lines are similar.
   (Ignoring that there are really two execution layers.)

   ```perl6
   'abc' ~~ 'XYZ'
   'XYZ'.ACCEPTS('abc')
   ```

   The important point to remember is that the right side of `~~` gets to decide how the smartmatch happens. The only way that can happen is if the method call was on it, not the left side.

(Note that all of the above also applies to `when` and `where` clauses. because they are also smartmatch features.)

---

So of course these have different results.

```perl6
%myth-objects.ACCEPTS("Oðinn")
%myth-objects ~~ "Oðinn"
```

These three are similar.

```perl6
         %myth-objects ~~ "Oðinn"
do given %myth-objects {  "Oðinn".ACCEPTS($_) }          # identical
                          "Oðinn".ACCEPTS(%myth-objects) # simplified
```

As are these

```perl6
                    %myth-objects.ACCEPTS("Oðinn")
do given "Oðinn" {  %myth-objects.ACCEPTS($_) }    # expanded to two layers
         "Oðinn" ~~ %myth-objects                  # smartmatched
```

Answer (score 6):

Is it not the other way:

```
say 'Oðinn' ~~ %myth-objects;
```

According to the doc:
The smartmatch operator aliases the left-hand side to $_ , then evaluates the right-hand side and calls .ACCEPTS($_) on it.